# Catel using IEditableObject

Tags: catel

I am testing Catel MVVM and I would like to use the implemented `IEditableObject`. I have got some questions, but the [documentation](https://docs.catelproject.com/5.7/catel-mvvm/view-models/creating-view-model-with-model-and-mappings/) I've found, isn't very detailed in this point.

Did someone have a helpful link, how I have to set this up or how it works, or something like this? Or should I really have a look to the source code, to get these points and get a feeling, how catel do the work.

The questions, that I have got, are these:

- What exactly does the method `SaveViewModelAsync()`?
- Where does it save the data, or where can I configurate it?
- How can I use it with `Orc.EntityFramework6`, or do I have this manually?
- What's the different between `SaveViewModelAsync()` and `SaveAsync()`?
- What's the different between `CancelViewModelAsync()` and `CancelAsync()`?

I can only cancel the editing one time. If I edit the same ViewModel again, the cancel has no effect anymore.
I think there is only an `BeginEdit()` missing after the first cancel, like this [documentation](https://docs.catelproject.com/5.7/introduction/mvvm/creating-view-models-with-catel/) suggests. Here some informations to this point:

1. I edit the ViewModel and the Model set the new value
2. I execute `CancelViewModelAsync()`, the setter in the Model is not touched
3. I edit the ViewModel and the Model set the new value. The current value is the original value
4. I execute `CancelViewModelAsync()`, nothing happened
5. I edit the ViewModel and the Model set the new value. The current value is the edited value from step 3, like the View shows

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of questions in a single question, but will try to answer them:

**Q1) What exactly does the method SaveViewModelAsync()**

It calls `IEditableObject.EndEdit` on all models that support it (and are decorated with the `ModelAttribute`

**Q2) Where does it save the data, or where can I configurate it?**

It just approves the changes to the model, it doesn't "save" anything. So for example, if you are using Catel models, it will commit the changes made by the VM. If you would cancel, it would revert the model back to the state it was when you initialized the VM.

**Q3) How can I use it with Orc.EntityFramework6, or do I have this manually?**

You have to do this manually. The VM's in Catel work with models, it's up to you when / where you persist them to (e.g. a database, disk, web service, etc)

**Q4) What's the different between SaveViewModelAsync() and SaveAsync()?**

`SaveViewModelAsync` is the public method being called and takes care of the plumbing for you. `SaveAsync` is a method you can override to add additional save logic (e.g. storing in database, update services, etc).

**Q5) What's the different between CancelViewModelAsync() and CancelAsync()?**

See Q4

Comment: Thank’s but can you explain it a bit more? I tested 2 ViewModels with the same model. If I change A, B will refreshed also, even if I didn’t call `SaveViewModelAsync()`. According to your answer, this should not happen. And could you answer, why I can’t call `CancelViewModelAsync()` two times? Information: The Properties have the `ViewModelToModel` Attribute.

Comment: If you are using the same model in 2 vm's with IEditableOBject at the same time, stuff won't work. Make sure that only 1 is the owner.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood the part “it will commit the changes”. It will not write the changes to the model, it will call the `EndEdit`, so that this last backup is obsolete. But why I can’t then revert twice? Is a new back up not instantly created? I started an github [issue](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/issues/1226), that includes this.

Comment: A backup is only created whenever you call BeginEdit. To save memory, Catel doesn't pro-actively create new backups.