# Catel Edit Master-Detail View multiple times

Tags: catel

I'm trying to edit a [Master-Detail View](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL/pages/2359348/Master+detail+example) multiple times in Catel.

**My question** is, if there is no common way in catel to handle a Master-Detail-View and multiple editions using the `SaveViewModelAsync` and `CancelViewModelAsync` methods?

The workflow works when my Master-ListItem is no UserControl with it's own ViewModel and when I change the selected Master-ListItem after save or cancel, so that a new ViewModel will be created. But I don't want to null or change the selection after a save/cancel. Also I have maybe to create a UserControl + ViewModel for the Master-ListItems.

**Restrictions of the question:**

I have got the information from Geert van Horrik from the discussion of his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853824/7790628), that

- multiple edit cycles are not supported directly
- one Model should only be accesd by one ViewModel

**Problem:**

I can use the the `SaveViewModelAsync` and `CancelViewModelAsync` only once. After that, the ViewModels which are alive

- will get no updates from the Model
- don't create a BackUp from the Data, so that the changes can be reverted again

**Code to Reproduce:**

I have created a [WPF Project](https://github.com/RCP161/MasterDeatil_Edit), where I tested this all.

**Possible solution:**

- I could use the [EditableObjectHelper](https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/58d964c15281728972d9f1326048fdf665045663/src/Catel.Core/Data/Helpers/EditableObjectHelper.cs) and handle this by myself
- I have to instantiate the VewModel again, after the save or cancel, like it happends on a selection change in my Example Code

**Restricion of the solution:**

- If I use a specialized UserControl for the ListItems of the Master-View, 2 ViewModels are looking on 1 Model. After the `SaveViewModelAsync` the ViewModel doesn't get any Notifications of the Model. So I would have to instantiate this ViewModel again too. But I would Breake the 1-1 relation of the ViewModel-Model.

**My conclusion:**

It seems, that I have to instantiate all these ViweModels and handle this workflow all by myself. It seems, that the `ViewModelLifetimeManagement.PartlyManual` (`CloseViewModelOnUnloaded` is Obsolete) doesn't work here. On selection change, always a new ViewModel will be created, the old one will probably just not be closed.

**I don't want to misuse the framework. Maybe I have missed something. I hope somebody can help me or give me a tip, how to handle this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the [answer of Geert van Horrik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148851/7790628), I **currently** ended up , don't using the `SaveViewModelAsync` and `CancelViewModelAsync` methods and handle the save and cancel by my own, so that the notification will not breake. I'm using the `GetChildViewModels()` method on the `ViewModelBase` and the `EditableObjectHelper.CancelEditObject(Model)`;

Answer (score 1):

Catel calls Save / Cancel as soon as the view model get's unloaded. If you want to do "intermediate" saves without changing the data model, you can:

1. Save the master list which will save the dirty models (you can directly modify the models from within your vm's)
2. Create a custom command (SaveData) that you can run from an explicit button (or input gesture binding) to save the data without calling SaveAsync on the vm